# Laravel error: 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch' on multiple file upload insert

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got a form which allows for multiple entries into a database. Each of these rows contains a file upload field.

The fields are created as follows:

```
{{ Form::select('revision[]', ['0' => '0', '1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5', '6' => '6'], '0', ['class' => 'form-control artwork-revision']); }}
{{ Form::text('product[]', false, ['class' => 'form-control artwork-product', 'placeholder' => 'Please enter the product name']) }}
{{ Form::file('file[]', ['class' => 'artwork-file']) }}
```

My controller has a foreach loop to enter each row into the database but when I run it, I get the following error message: `preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array`

The code works when it's adapted for a single file upload (i.e. without the foreach loop and with only one row to be inserted, fields created without the square brackets)

How can I get past this error and enter the info into the database?

Here is the foreach loop in my controller and a `var_dump` of the object.

Controller foreach loop:

```
$files = Input::file('file');

foreach($files as $file) {
    // it's a new artwork row
    $artwork = new Artwork;

    // get the vars
    $artwork->job_id = Input::get('job_id');
    $artwork->revision = Input::get('revision');
    $artwork->product = Input::get('product');

    // it's pending
    $artwork->status = 'P';

    // sort the filename...
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file = $file->move(base_path() . '/public/artwork/' . Input::get('job_id'), $filename);

    // ...and put it in the $artwork object
    $artwork->filename = 'artwork/' . $artwork->job_id . '/' . $filename;

    // save it
    $artwork->save();
}
```

var_dump($artwork) output - note that only one image filename is showing in this rather than two:

```
object(Artwork)#243 (21) {
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "deleted_at"
  }
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "job_id"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "filename"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "status"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "revision"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "product"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "reason"
  }
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(8) "artworks"
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    ["job_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["revision"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    ["product"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "Twist USB Drive"
      [1]=>
      string(19) "Eco Twist USB Drive"
    }
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "P"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(24) "artwork/5/12345-test.jpg"
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["morphClass":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["forceDeleting":protected]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my new 'store' controller that solves the issue:

```
$artwork = new Artwork;

        // standard bits
        $artwork->job_id = Input::get('job_id');
        $artwork->status = 'P';

        // variables
        $artwork->revision = Input::get('revision');
        $artwork->product = Input::get('product');
        $artwork->file = Input::file('file');

        // count how many pieces of artwork are being uploaded (this could be any field)
        $count = count($artwork->revision);

        /* multi-file upload */
        $i = 0;

        // process each piece       
        foreach($artwork as $a) {
            while($count > $i) {
                // it's a new piece of artwork
                $a = new Artwork;

                // standard bits to object
                $a->job_id = $artwork->job_id;
                $a->status = $artwork->status;

                // revision and product name to object
                $a->revision = $artwork->revision[$i];
                $a->product = $artwork->product[$i];

                // get the file and move it
                $file = $artwork->file[$i];
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $movefile = $file->move(base_path() . '/public/artwork/' . $artwork->job_id, $filename);

                // filename to object
                $a->filename = $filename;

                // save the object to db
                $a->save();

                // add 1 to the count
                $i++;
            }
        }

        return Redirect::route('jobs.index');
```

Comment: -1 This is part of your question. It is not an answer.

Comment: No, it's the working controller that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't even select multiple files. Replace your file field with this one it has multiple attribute set to true which will allow multiple files to be selected at once and returns an array of files.

```
{{ Form::file('file[]', ['class' => 'artwork-file','multiple' => true]) }}
```

Comment: I need each file upload field to only take one file, not multiple, so I'm not using the `multiple` attribute on the form field. I've given it a go anyhow but to no avail. Thanks for your response though.